# Add filter to Publisher mail merge from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, mailmerge, publisher

I have a macro in Excel that runs a mail merge in Publisher.

How do I add this filter to the current code?

> sheet="ALL Sections$", colIndex= icol, criteria="part1name"

Code to run mail merge in Publisher:

```vb
    Dim strWorkbookName As String
    Dim pubSource As Object
    Dim mrgMain As MailMerge
    Dim appPub As Object
    Dim FileLink As String

    FileLink = [Rank1MailMerge].Value
    Set appPub = CreateObject("Publisher.Application")
    strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
    Set pubSource = appPub.Open(FileLink)
    Set mrgMain = pubSource.MailMerge

    pubSource.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
      bstrDataSource:=strWorkbookName, _
      bstrTable:="ALL Sections$", _
      fNeverPrompt:=True

    With mrgMain.DataSource
        .FirstRecord = pbDefaultFirstRecord
        .LastRecord = pbDefaultLastRecord
    End With
    mrgMain.Execute False, pbMergeToNewPublication
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solved] I finally figured out how to apply my filters and a few other problems i found along the way - there is hardly any info about publisher mail merge out there.

code:

```
Sub MergeToPub ()
Dim strWorkbookName As String
Dim pubSource As Object
Dim mrgMain As MailMerge
Dim appPub As New Publisher.Application
Dim FileLink As String

  strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
  FileLink = [MailMergePub].Value
  appPub.ActiveWindow.Visible = True
  Set pubSource = appPub.Open(FileLink)
  Set mrgMain = pubSource.MailMerge

'before i added this next line of code, for some reason 
'it added the same data source twice and merged duplicate results
 If pubSource.MailMerge.DataSource.Name = strWorkbookName Then GoTo ContinueCode


    pubSource.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
        bstrDataSource:=strWorkbookName, _
        bstrTable:="Sheet1$", _
        fNeverPrompt:=True

ContinueCode:
'this adds two filters
    With mrgMain.DataSource
        .Filters.Add Column:="Column1", _
           Comparison:=msoFilterComparisonEqual, _
           Conjunction:=msoFilterConjunctionAnd, _
           bstrCompareTo:="Name"

      .Filters.Add Column:="Column2", _
           Comparison:=msoFilterComparisonNotEqual, _
           Conjunction:=msoFilterConjunctionAnd, _
           bstrCompareTo:="yes"
           .ApplyFilter

        .FirstRecord = pbDefaultFirstRecord
        .LastRecord = pbDefaultLastRecord
    End With

mrgMain.Execute False, pbMergeToNewPublication
pubSource.Close
 Set appPub = Nothing
 Set pubSource = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Great!! Well Tried